# How to print the contents of all revisions of a particular file in Mercurial?

Tags: powershell, mercurial

Let's say I have 5 revisions of a README file. How do I view them all in [Mercurial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercurial)?

It would be nice to be able to limit the output, similar to:

```
hg log -l 10
```

I'm using [PowerShell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell), so combined solutions are also welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know Powershell syntax, but you're looking for the `hg cat` command. Combined with the answer to [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078976/view-all-revision-numbers-that-made-changes-to-a-particular-file-in-mercurial) I would do it like this in a Unix shell (zsh in my case):

```
for r in $(hg log --template '{rev} ' README); do hg cat -r $r README; done
```

I first get all the revisions in which `README` was changed. They will be put into a big string like this:

```
% hg log --template '{rev} ' README
822 804 688 681 629 539 538
```

You then iterate over these revision numbers and call `hg cat` on each.

Comment: Thank you Martin, very well written.