# View all revision numbers that made changes to a particular file in Mercurial

Tags: git, mercurial

I would like to see all revision numbers that made any changes to a particular file.
The output should look like follows:

```
20
27
59
```

If it is not possible, is it possible with Git?

Thank you.

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would want a Git solution if you have a Mercurial repository?

Comment: Still considering the optimal DVCS for me, but more and more leaning toward mercurial

Comment: Ah, okay :-) I just sounded to me like you already had a Mercurial repository and then I could not understand how a Git solution would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the **[template system](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/customizing-the-output-of-mercurial.html)** in Mercurial. To get the revision number for the file `README` you'll do:

```
hg log --template '{rev}\n' README
```

If you need the changeset hashes instead, then it's:

```
hg log --template '{node|short}\n' README
```

See `hg help templating` for more help. You can find the same help [online](http://www.selenic.com/mercurial/hg.1.html) (search for "Template Usage").

Comment: Yeah, templates are a much under-used part of Mercurial.

Answer (score 2):

With git, you can run

```
git rev-list HEAD -- path/to/file
```

and you'll see a list of the commits which changed that file. Note that you can also run for example

```
gitk --all path/to/file
```

to open gitk, only showing commits for that file

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an ancient question, but I had the same dilemma and discovered this answer:
`hg log file_name`
It works as expected, I like it.